# Prevent tmux from printing line numbers

Tags: tmux

I am scrolling back in Tmux using the key combination + [, and as I scroll up, I see this on the right hand side.

[image]

What is this feature even called? It's extremely frustrating because it interrupts my data as I see it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The line number should remain in the top line only and not appear on any lower lines, if that is what is happening (it is not entirely clear from your picture). If it does appear on lower lines I suggest you make sure your tmux version is up to date, make sure TERM outside tmux is correct for your terminal and perhaps try a different terminal entirely and see if it happens there too.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same exact issue, and as a relatively new user of tmux/xterm it wasn't entirely clear to me what to do here and I ended up revisiting the previous answer twice during my googling... I could have used an example :)

Try this:

**BASH/ZSH**

```
> export TERM=screen
> tmux
```

**CSH/TCSH**

```
> setenv TERM screen
> tmux
```

Also, disable/comment out any right-hand-side prompt stuff (RPROMPT) in your shell config. For instance, I had git data displaying on the right side of the prompt in my .zshrc as the following, which was interfering with the tmux right-hand-side stuff:

```
    # autoload -Uz vcs_info
    # precmd_vcs_info() { vcs_info }
    # precmd_functions+=( precmd_vcs_info )
    # RPROMPT=\$vcs_info_msg_0_
    # zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%F{5}(%b) %r%f'
    # zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
```

And definitely keep your tmux version up to date as mentioned in the other answer.